# AWS boto3 Quicksight "AllowedDomains" parameter non-existent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, boto, amazon-quicksight

my problem is that im calling the boto3 quicksight API with this function call:

```
            response = quickSight.generate_embed_url_for_registered_user(
            AllowedDomains=[
                'http://localhost',
            ],
            AwsAccountId=awsAccountId,
            UserArn='arn:aws:quicksight:' + identityRegion + ':' + awsAccountId + ':user/default/' + roleName + '/' + userName,
            SessionLifetimeInMinutes=adjustedSessionDuration,
            ExperienceConfiguration={'Dashboard': {'InitialDashboardId': d['DashboardId']}},
            )
```

This is in accordance to the documentation [Found here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.generate_embed_url_for_registered_user)

The reason I´m using "AllowedDomains" is, so that I can develop locally without having to deploy my code for every change.

This is also described in AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedding-run-time.html).

I'm starting to think though that the AWS boto3 documentation is wrong, because I am using the newest version of boto3, but I get an error every time, since boto3 doesn't seem to contain the parameter "AllowedDomains":

[Screenshot showing error together with correct boto3 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1smSs.png)

```
Unknown parameter in input: "AllowedDomains", must be one of: AwsAccountId, SessionLifetimeInMinutes, UserArn, ExperienceConfiguration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 21, in lambda_handler
    response = GetQuickSightResponse.handler(event, context, mode)
  File "/var/task/GetQuickSightResponse.py", line 280, in handler
    response = getUrl(recursionDepth=1)
  File "/var/task/GetQuickSightResponse.py", line 213, in getUrl
    response = quickSight.generate_embed_url_for_registered_user(
  File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 878, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
  File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 939, in _convert_to_request_dict
    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
  File "/opt/python/botocore/validate.py", line 381, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
```

Does someone have an idea of how to fix this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I am getting the same error on javascript aws-sdk as well. Did you manage to fix it? Is it just a matter of updating?